# I Intrinsict gas too low

Tags: mist

I am using the Mist wallet to play on the Test Net. I am trying to deploy the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }

contract MyToken {
    /* Public variables of the token */
    string public standard = 'Token 0.1';
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /* This notifies clients about the amount burnt */
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyToken(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (_to == 0x0) throw;                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }

    /* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /* Approve and then communicate the approved contract in a single tx */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }        

    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (_to == 0x0) throw;                                // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;     // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                           // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                             // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;            // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                      // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                                // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                // Check if the sender has enough
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                               // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which I got from here: https://ethereum.org/token#the-code

The problem I face, when I try and deploy it I get an error: "Intrinsic gas too low".[image: Intrinsic gas too low]

The code looks like this in the app:[image: EthCode]

Not sure if I am just doing something really stupid or if there is an issue with the wallet / code etc...

Quite new to all this.

Wallet version: [image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with Ethereum Wallet/Mist, I think it is fixed in the latest version (0.8.10). You see the estimated fee and the maximum fee in the first image? Click on that 153,001 and make it more than 958,600, and it should work.